# Pdf form fill with mysql data

Tags: mysql, pdf

I have pdf form, Which need to fill by mysql data. Is it possible?. Can some one share some examples?. Html forms and convert then to pdf forms are useless for this purpose because i must need pdf form should be filled.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. Which one will be the most appropriate one depends on the actual workflow, the tools available, how often this has to happen etc.

Among the possibilities, we have:

• exporting an FDF from the database: FDF is the Forms Data Format which is native PDF, and is described in the PDF description (as well as ISO 32000). FDF is a structured text file, which means that it is possible to assemble it in MySQL. This FDF will then be imported into the blank PDF form.

• the same as above, but using XFDF, which is an XML representation of FDF.

• exporting a tab-delimited file from the database, and importing it into the form as a file attachment. According logic in the form reads in the tab-delimited data and fills it into the according fields.

• connecting to the database using SOAP. Appropriate logic in the form will take the data and distribute it accordingly to the fields.

• (for bigger volumes) create FDFs as above, but then use a server-side form filling application, such as FDFMerge by Appligent.

As said, the approach to be used depends on the project and its circumstances.